# How to create a county / people URL structure for PHP profile pages

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Im currently building a PHP driven website, on my homepage I have X users, each user shows a picture and their name. I want to create a button to view this persons profile that then takes them to another page with all of there relevant information pulled from the table.

I want my URLS to appear like `mysite.com/county/people/liam-gallagher.php` as opposed to `mysite.com/profile.php?id=1`

How is this done with URL rewriting, or shall I create those directories on my server?

Comment: Yes, URL rewriting. Only tangentially related, but this may set you on the right path: https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router#what-urls-are-and-how-to-set-up-routing

Answer (score 4):

When you see something like this, it's *usually* the result of URL rewriting. Creating physical folders for categories and counties would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

first of all u catch all request to index page using on your htaccess file using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

then u can use header to redirect as u like .

Answer (score 0):

Make use of your web servers url rewriting using regular expressions or even better: Use some kind of *routing* provided by a framework. Routing is the standard way of web application MVC style mapping of requests to appropriate actions. If you don't use any kind of MVC framework, you should think about using at least a very simple one.